# useless links on careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Not sure if it's time to report *minor* issues with careers 2.0, but it's open for some time already. Therefore...

[image]

*Adding a Location* link does nothing.
*15% complete* link points to profile itself (same page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out, it should be resolved.